# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.provider.CalendarContract$Calendars

Tags: android

The Calendar Provider has been change in 4.0. In 2.3, Calendar Provider is android.provider.Calendar and in 4.0, Calendar provider is android.provider.CalendarContract. So it can't run successfully in 4.0 if the source code is not modified.

How modified the code?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use both, use this check too see if its ICS or not and use the relevant code in each :)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) 
{
//4.0 and above
}
else
{

}
```